MacBook Air ethernet stops working
I have a 2020 MacBook with Intel CPU and macOS Ventura (currently). I've recently bought a unitek D1026B hub. I plug the ethernet from xiaomi 4a router WAN port to the hub, and the hub to my laptop.
When I use my work laptop with windows it works fine.
When I switch to using macOS, the internet shuts down (especially when I start some games like League of Legends). In the options it indicates that the connection is fine (green dot) but I can't connect to any website.
This issue has been occurringfor 2 weeks now and I haven't found anything that would help.
Things I've tried:

change ethernet cable (2 different ones and works fine with windows)
downloading special drivers for hub
rebooting Mac or router (several times)

-remove and add back the ethernet device in network settings
-using sudo ifconfig en4 down/up (to restart network device I guess)
-changing location in network settings
-connecting directly from socket in walls (I live in dorm) and skipping router
-downgrading from macOS Sonoma to Ventura
-booting in safe mode (still lost connection)
-renew DHCP lease (it won't even get correct ip address)
From all of this I think it is some MacOS issue but I don't want to downgrade it even more and don't know how to solve it.
Also I can't change Hardware settings in network settings I can only switch from automatic to manual but when I switch for example speed it won't save.
After I downgraded to Ventura it was okay for about 2 days but after that time it started "crashing" again. My dorm officials require to use DHCP so I can't use static IP or DNS. Does anyone have any idea how to track the issue and how to solve it?
